# Build ros-fuerte from source, agains boost 1.49.0

Tags: ros, boost, ros-fuerte, build-from-source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, all:

I'm just wondering how I can build ros-fuerte from source again boost 1.49.0?
My environment: Ubuntu 12.04
ROS version: fuerte

I just want to use some of the manually installed packages, instead of the default ones grabbed from the repository.
Since I'm not using the default boost 1.46.1, I obtained the following error messages

```
executing command [sudo apt-get install -y ros-fuerte-ros]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-fuerte-ros : Depends: libboost-all-dev but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: ros-fuerte-rospack but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
  apt: command [sudo apt-get install -y ros-fuerte-ros] failed
```

at the last but 2 step, say

```
rosdep install -ay
```

when building Higher-level/tools (Layer 2) .

Can anybody give me a hand?

cheers
Pei

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36029/build-ros-fuerte-from-source,-agains-boost-1.49.0/) by [jiapei100](https://answers.ros.org/users/1310/jiapei100/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-06-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on 2012-07-08**:
Please replace the `blockquote`s with '>'. No closing tags needed. This would make your question easier to read. If you just want to preserve formatting of your copy/pasted console text, use '    ' (four spaces) in front of each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could you clarify the technical details a bit more?

> I'm just wondering how I can build ros-fuerte from source again boost 1.49.0? [..] I just want to use some of the manually installed packages, instead of the default ones grabbed from the repository.

Does this mean you want to build *all* of ROS from source, but not its dependencies, or do you want to build *some* ROS packages from source (to be able to build them with boost 1.49)?

---

In case you want to build all of ROS from source, but satisfy some of the dependencies with locally installed packages /source (which are not present in `apt`'s database):

I'm not sure about compatibility of Fuerte with Boost 1.49, but for the Ubuntu/Debian side you could look into [equivs](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-howto/ch-helpers.en.html). This would allow you to create a *meta-package* with which you could trick `apt` into thinking that the prerequisites have been installed.

This is somewhat of an 'advanced' technique though, as you can create some pretty interesting `apt` conflicts this way, but might offer you a way around the strict dependencies.

---

Originally posted by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) with karma: 1416 on 2012-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0